# Pam_unix sshd authentication failure even though the login works?

Tags: linux, pam, winbind

I have a server that is configured with winbind and samba to provide active directory authentication. The active directory integration works fine however whenever I authenticate I see the following errors:

### **Errors**

Authentication:

```
May 11 00:25:29 SERVER sshd[28119]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=x.x.x.x  user=USERNAME
```

Sudo:

```
May 11 01:33:14 SERVER sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname=USER_NAME uid=2005125 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/2 ruser=USER_NAME rhost=  user=USER_NAME
```

### **Configuration**

/etc/samba/smb.conf:

```
[global]
        workgroup = WORKGROUP
        realm = DOMAIN NAME
        security = ADS
        winbind enum users = Yes
        winbind enum groups = Yes
        winbind use default domain = No
        winbind separator = +
        kerberos method = secrets and keytab
        idmap config * : backend = autorid
        idmap config * : range = 1000000-19999999
        idmap config * : rangesize = 1000000
        template shell = /bin/bash
        netbios name = SERVERNAME
```

/etc/pam.d/system-auth

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        sufficient    pam_winbind.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_winbind.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_winbind.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     optional      pam_mkhomedir.so umask=0077
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_winbind.so
```

/etc/pam.d/sshd

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       required     pam_sepermit.so
auth       substack     password-auth
auth       include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-auth      optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      password-auth
password   include      password-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      password-auth
session    include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-session   optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
```

sshd_config:

```
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem sftp  /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
AuthorizedKeysCommand /opt/aws/bin/eic_run_authorized_keys %u %f
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser ec2-instance-connect
Banner /etc/motd
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

How can i get this log fixed?